# Changing fields of class in java

Tags: java, list

So, I'm still learning java and coding so the resolution may be obvious but I just can't see it.
I'm writing a code about stars and constelations for uni assignment.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.*;


public class Main {

    static public class Constellation {
        public List<Star> constellation;
        public String nameOfConstellation;

        public Constellation(List<Star> constellation, String nameOfConstellation) {
            this.constellation = constellation;
            this.nameOfConstellation = nameOfConstellation;
        }

        public List<Star> getConstellation() {
            return constellation;
        }
    }

    static public class Star {

       // private String categoryName;
        private Constellation constellation;
        private String nameOfConstelation;

        public String getCategoryName() {
            int index = constellation.getConstellation().indexOf(this);
            String categoryName;
            return categoryName = GreekLetter.values[index] + " " + this.constellation.nameOfConstellation;
        }


        public void deleteStar(Star x) {
            this.constellation.constellation.remove(x);


        }
    }
    public enum GreekLetter {

        alfa,
        beta,
        gamma,
        delta,
        epsilon,
        dzeta,
        eta;

        static public final GreekLetter[] values = values();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Star x = new Star();
        List<Star> fishCon = new ArrayList<>();
        Constellation Fish = new Constellation(fishCon, "Fish");
        x.constellation=Fish;
        fishCon.add(x);
        x.getCategoryName();


        Star y = new Star();
        y.constellation=Fish;
        fishCon.add(y);

        y.getCategoryName();
        x.deleteStar(x);


        for (Star w : Fish.constellation)
        {
            System.out.println(w.getCategoryName());
        }

    }
}
```

My point is to Update field categoryName after deleting one star. categoryName value is set in order of adding another star. For example I have first star - the name will be Alfa + nameOfConstelation. Second star - Beta + nameOfConstelation. When I call method deleteStar() I want to update all categoyName of my stars in constelation. Calling methods in deleteStar() doesn't work probably due to add() in  setCategoryName. I would really appreciate any hints!

Comment: Your design appears to be broken. I would create a Constellation class that holds a `List<Star>` and create a List of Constellations using that. Your Star objects could each hold a reference to the Constellation that contains it.

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't change anything. Also  corrected my code.

Comment: Regardless, what I am suggesting is in fact correct, and you'd do well to show your code using this structure and the problems you specifically are having with *this* code

Comment: The category name will be determined dynamically by the order the Star is held in the Constellation object. You appear to be over-complicating things.

Comment: Side note: no reason to make Star a nested class. Put it and Constellation classes in their own `.java` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this appears to be homework, I am not posting code in this answer but rather giving suggestions that can help you create your own workable code:

- Create a class called Constellation that holds the Stars in an `List<Star> starList = new ArrayList<>();`
- Give Constellation a `public List<Star> getStarList()` method
- Give each Star a Constellation field to hold the Constellation that contains this Star
- Give each Star a `getCategoryName()` method that gets the Constellation object, iterates through its starList using a for-loop until it finds the `this` Star, and then that returns the appropriate name based on the index of the Star in the list.
- Thus, if a Star is removed from the starList, the category names of all the other Stars held by that Constellation will update automatically and dynamically

Also,

- You can give Constellation a `public void deleteStar(Star star)` method where it removes the Star parameter from its starList
- You can also give Star a `public void deleteFromConstellation()` method where it checks its Constellation field, constellation, and if not null, calls `constellation.deleteStar(this);` and then sets the constellation field to null
- Get rid of the `private String categoryName;` field in Star. This should be a *calculated* field, meaning the `public String getCategoryName()` does not return a field, but a String based on code (as described above).
- It first checks that Star's constellation field is not null
- It then gets the index of the Star in the Constellation's starList (I have given my Constellation class a `public int getIndexOfStar(Star star)` method.
- It then uses this, the GreekLetter class, and the `constellation.getName()` method to create a String to return

Done.

Since you've figured this out, this is another way to code it:

```
public class SkyMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Constellation fish = new Constellation("Fish");

        Star x = new Star();
        Star y = new Star();
        fish.addStar(x);
        fish.addStar(y);
        
        System.out.println("before removing x");
        System.out.println("x category name: " + x.getCategoryName());
        System.out.println("y category name: " + y.getCategoryName());
        System.out.println("fish constellation: " + fish);
        
        fish.removeStar(x);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("after removing x");        
        System.out.println("x category name: " + x.getCategoryName());
        System.out.println("y category name: " + y.getCategoryName());
        System.out.println("fish constellation: " + fish);
    }
}
```

```
public class Star {
    private Constellation constellation;
    
    public void setConstellation(Constellation constellation) {
        this.constellation = constellation;
    }
    
    public void removeFromConstellation() {
        if (constellation != null) {
            constellation.removeStar(this);
        }
    }
    
    public String getCategoryName() {
        if (constellation != null) {
            int index = constellation.getIndexOfStar(this);
            return GreekLetter.getGreekLetter(index).getName() + " " + constellation.getName();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getCategoryName();
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Constellation implements Iterable<Star> {
    private String name;
    private List<Star> starList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Constellation(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public List<Star> getStarList() {
        return starList;
    }
    
    public void addStar(Star star) {
        starList.add(star);
        star.setConstellation(this);
    }
    
    public void removeStar(Star star) {
        if (starList.contains(star)) {
            starList.remove(star);
            star.setConstellation(null);
        }
    }
    
    public int getIndexOfStar(Star star) {
        return starList.indexOf(star);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Star> iterator() {
        return starList.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Constellation [name=" + name + ", starList=" + starList + "]";
    }
    
    
}
```

```
public enum GreekLetter
{
    ALPHA("alpha", 0),
    BETA("beta", 1),
    GAMMA("gamma", 2),
    DELTA("delta", 3),
    EPSILON("epsilon", 4),
    ZETA("zeta", 5),
    ETA("eta", 6);
    
    private String name;
    private int index;
    
    private GreekLetter(String name, int index) {
        this.name = name;
        this.index = index;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }
    
    public static GreekLetter getGreekLetter(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index > values().length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("for index " + index);
        } else {
            return values()[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: public String getCategoryName() {
            int index = constellation.getStarList().indexOf(this);
            return categoryName = GreekLetter.values[index] + " " + this.constellation.nameOfConstellation;
        }
something like that?

Comment: @majszixo: try it and see

Comment: It still doesn't change names. It indeed deletes star but names stay the same way.

Comment: @majszixo: then you're likely doing something wrong. Please consider updating your question with your latest code

Comment: It works after calling method getCategoryName() in main after deletting star but in my opinion this looks awfully bad.

Comment: @majszixo: Any solution should look clean. Something is likely off in your code

Comment: @majszixo: also, get rid of the `private String categoryName;` field in Star. This should be a *calculated* field, meaning the `public String getCategoryName()` does not return a field, but a String based on code (as described above.

Comment: And deleting private String categoryName was the issue. Now it works perfectly fine. Thank you very much for your time and patience!